# Can a static method be overridden

Tags: c#, .net

could anyone explain in detail that a static method be overridden in extended or inherited class.with a sample example or reference links or tutorials.

Comment: don't understand downvote on this question...

Comment: @Tigran: The asker didn't bother to search before posting. I could probably get out there and find a duplicate for this if it wasn't already closed now.

Comment: @Tigran, Well how much time do you think the OP has spent searching/trying to find an answer?

Answer (score 5):

[static methods cannot be overriden.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can't override a static method in inherited/extended classes.